# Create an object and his many to many relationships with extrafields in one form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-orm

I'm on Django 2.2 and here are my simplified models:

```py
class Course(CustomModelClass):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
    components = models.ManyToManyField('Component', through='CourseComponent')

class Component(CustomModelClass):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)

class CourseComponent(CustomModelClass):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    component = models.ForeignKey(Component, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
```

My relationships work well no problem on that. Now arrive the moment I do a ModelForm to manage that.

Here is my form for now:

```py
class CourseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'group', 'components']
        model = Course
```

And same it works quite well if my quantity has a null=True parameter but of course when I put it at False, it obviously doesn't work anymore.

What I wanted to do is to have in my form a way to select components and set a quantity for each of them. I don't really care how it looks like it can be a checkbox with the name of the component and a numberfield or many select list to select the component and a number field, it's not the important part.

More clearly I want to create an object and his manytomany relationships with extra field in the same form.

My problem right now is that of course I have no access to the quantities in the form.

Any idea?

Comment: I posted a response based on my understanding of your issue. if that is not what you are looking for, try to explain your blocking point a little more

Comment: @Houda Thanks for answering but my problem is not here. I try to create an object and all his manytomany relationships and their quantity in the same form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### add extra field in modelform directly:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Course, Component
class CourseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['name']
        model = Course

class ComponentForm(forms.Form):
    component = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Component.objects.all())
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(initial=0, required=False, min_value=0)

ComponentFormSet = forms.formset_factory(ComponentForm, extra=3)
```

#### views.py concerned

```
def handler(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CourseForm(request.POST)
        formset = ComponentFormSet(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            # do your business
    form = CourseForm()  #it could set initial data here for form,etc
    formset = ComponentFormSet()
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form':form, 'formset':formset})
```

#### you_template.html concerned

```
{% extends 'admin/base_site.html'%}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content%}
<div class="col-md-10">
    <form action={% url "course" %} method='post' role='form' class="form-inline">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}<br>
        {{ formset.management_form}}
        {% for fm in formset %}
        {{ fm }}<br>
        {% endfor%}
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock%}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I tried it, but in this case I juste have the possibility to select one component with a quantity, in my case I have to create one course, with multiple components, and each one has a quantity in the relationship

Comment: Make use of formset

Comment: Yes that's exactly my question: How to do a formset multi models.

Comment: I have fixed it for you.

Comment: So I understand that it's impossible to do it in one unic form

Comment: if the relationship is through foreignkey, it could be resolved by inlineformset_factory. but in fact, it still involve several form or formset in base codes. you can go through the source code of ModelAdmin which could inspire you.

Comment: I already checked that but you have to give an instance to the inline formset from the first model. And I don't have it because I need to create it at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find this proposition interesting:

Views.py:

```
def view1(request):
    CourseComponentFormSet = formset_factory(CourseComponentForm, extra=Component.objects.count())
    content = {'form': CourseComponentFormSet}
    return render(request, 'stack/edit.html', content)


def view2(request, mycourse):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {}
        for p in request.POST:
            if p.startswith('form'):
                data[p] = request.POST[p]
        j = 0
        while j < int(data['form-MAX_NUM_FORMS']):
            if data['form-' + str(j) + '-quantity'] == '':
                data['form-' + str(j) + '-quantity'] = 0
                data['form-' + str(j) + '-course'] = mycourse
            else:
                data['form-' + str(j) + '-course'] = mycourse
            j += 1
        CourseComponentFormSet = formset_factory(CourseComponentForm)
        formset = CourseComponentFormSet(data)
        if formset.is_valid():
            j = 0
            mylist = []
            while j < int(data['form-MAX_NUM_FORMS']):
                if data['form-' + str(j) + '-quantity'] == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    Courses = get_object_or_404(Course, name=mycourse)
                    Components = get_object_or_404(Component, id=int(data['form-' + str(j) + '-component']))
                    Courses.components.add(Components,
                                           through_defaults={'quantity': data['form-' + str(j) + '-quantity']})
                j += 1

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('stack:view1'))
        else:
            errors = formset.errors
            ini = []
            i = 0
            nb = Component.objects.count()
            while i < nb:
                ini.append({'course': mycourse})
                i += 1
            CourseComponentFormSet = formset_factory(CourseComponentForm, max_num=nb)
            formset = CourseComponentFormSet(initial=ini)
            content = {'form': formset, 'course': mycourse, 'errors': errors}
            return render(request, 'stack/edit.html', content)
    else:
        if Course.objects.filter(name__exact=mycourse):
            pass
        else:
            Course.objects.create(**{'name': mycourse})
        ini = []
        i = 0
        nb = Component.objects.count()
        while i < nb:
            ini.append({'course': mycourse})
            i += 1
        CourseComponentFormSet = formset_factory(CourseComponentForm, max_num=nb)
        formset = CourseComponentFormSet(initial=ini)
        content = {'form': formset, 'course': mycourse}
        return render(request, 'stack/edit.html', content)
```

model.py

```
class Component(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
    components = models.ManyToManyField('Component', through='CourseComponent')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CourseComponent(models.Model):
    component = models.ForeignKey(Component, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CourseComponent, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class CourseComponentForm(Form):

    course = CharField(label='Course')
    component = ChoiceField(label='Component')
    quantity = IntegerField(label='Quantity')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs, ):
        super(CourseComponentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['component'].choices = tuple(Component.objects.all().values_list(flat=False))
        self.fields['quantity'].widget.attrs['style'] = "margin:15px 56% 15px 0%;"
        self.fields['course'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = "True"
        self.fields['course'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = "disabled"
```

edit.html

```
<body>
<label>Course:</label><input id="myinput" type="text"><button onclick="myfunction()">send</button><br>'
    <form action='' id='myform' method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" onclick="submit()">submit</button>
     </form>
{{errors}}
</body>

<script>

{% if mycourse %}
{% endif %}

function submit() {
document.getElementById('myform').action="/stack/view2/"+mycourse;
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}


function myfunction() {
    var course = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
    chemin ="\/stack\/view2\/"+course;
     window.location.replace(chemin);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the migrations are not a problem. The problem is that I want to create an object and his manytomany relationships with their extra field in one form.

The modelForm you provide can not give me what I want. It will create a select containing the list of courses. But I want to create one :)

Comment: You want one Form for three models, that's it?

Comment: every course has one quantity or every Course Component has one quantity

Comment: Normally just 2 models will be updated Course and Course component. The third one (the components) is already filled but is needed to fill the CourseComponents

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But I have to do that for a setting page with like 30 forms in the same page so I have to make it easy to manage nevermind the form. I will stay on the previous answer. But thank you very much for your help

Comment: Sorry I fogot some unseful lines. Please can you explain how can you save the couple (compenent. Quantity) for the right course?

Comment: What i do basicly I get the 2 forms I save the course one first ang get the id than I loop on the formset to add this id and save the form